# How can I safely migrate from inline security group rules to seperate security_group_rule resources in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I initially set up my security groups as inline rules, but now realize there are a lot of problems with that. I want to migrate the security groups to use separate resources for the rules, however, when I do that it says it will remove the existing rules and recreate them. Since the security rules depend on the security group, I can’t even add the new rules first then remove the old ones.

How can I migrate the security group without temporarily removing all of the rules?

EDIT:

Looking at another case, it seems like this only happens if you change the cidr blocks for one or more of the rules at the same time that you split the rules out into their own resources.

However, in the case where I just split it out without changing the rules, I can't figure out how to update the state. The plan shows the new rules getting created, but refreshing does nothing, there isn't a way to import them, and when I try to run apply I get:

```
Error: [WARN] A duplicate Security Group rule was found on (sg-XXX). This may be
a side effect of a now-fixed Terraform issue causing two security groups with
identical attributes but different source_security_group_ids to overwrite each
other in the state. See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/2376 for more
information and instructions for recovery. Error message: the specified rule "peer: 10.XX.XX.XX/27, TCP, from port: XX, to port: XX, ALLOW" already exists

  on ../modules/security-group/main.tf line 51, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "XXX":
  51: resource aws_security_group_rule XXX {
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [mcve] please? This should include the original code, the migrated code (with the separate rules resources) and the plan output.

Comment: You can create a new security group with rule resources and replace the old SG with the new SG wherever required, then remove the old SG. Or you can use create_before_destroy Have you tried that?

Comment: Does create_before_destroy wait for the new rules to be created before destroying the old security group?